# Block access to phpmyadmin page from other computers over LAN Network except Localhost.?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, httpd.conf

Is it possible to block access to phpMyAdmin page or the xampp Settings page for other computers over the LAN network? But in the same way it should be accessible for localhost or 127.0.0.1, I tried to set in the httpd.conf page as

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

But when I did so I was not able to access the site with the address `http://myhostname/website` from my computer or from any other computer from the network.

I would like to block the xampp settings page for other computers but they should be able to access the website.

Comment: Did you try changing \conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf ?

Comment: Not exactly but i had to comment out the Allow From section completely and add only => Allow From ::1 Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable access from your network, Open `httpd-xampp.conf` located in `xampp-folder\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

Change this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

To this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache. Now `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` will result 403 Forbidden error.

For more info read you can read http://www.hellothupten.com/2013/11/24/block-access-to-phpmyadmin-from-lan-network-on-xampp/

Comment: to add another ip, I just added another line of this -> Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \

Answer (score 0):

You need only to change your httpd conf file.

Comment the value `Require all granted` by adding a `#` (`#Require all granted`),
and add `Require local` for the informations `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">`

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
```

Add:

```
Require local
```

Make these paths accessible only from the host.